# How to specify number of digits to output for real numbers in Jansson

Tags: c, json

How can I specify a fixed number of digits to output after the decimal point when using Jansson's json_dumps or json_dumpf() to output real numbers?

I tried Jansson's new JSON_REAL_PRECISION flag, but that specifies the maximum number of significant digits, not a fixed number of digits after the decimal point.

Basically I'm looking for something in Jansson that behaves like the following call to printf in C (with expected output of 123.12346):

```
printf("%.5f", 123.123456789);
```

[EDIT]

Here's some sample code to illustrate the output styles I've tried so far (requires Jansson 2.7+):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jansson.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  json_t *json = json_object();

  json_object_set_new(json, "foo", json_real(123.123456789));
  printf("Output of json_dumps() for 123.123456789: %s\n", json_dumps(json, 0));
  printf("Again, but using JSON_REAL_PRECISION(5) : %s\n", json_dumps(json, JSON_REAL_PRECISION(5)));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Output of json_dumps() for 123.123456789: {"foo": 123.123456789}
Again, but using JSON_REAL_PRECISION(5) : {"foo": 123.12}
```

Again, I need a way to output a fixed number of digits after the decimal (e.g. **123.12346**), anyone know how to achieve this?.

Comment: store it as a string?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Clever, but in my case the json objects will be consumed externally and this will probably lead to confusion. If it were only for internal use I would use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I was recently trying to limit json data to at most 2 decimal places, and I initially thought that I could use `JSON_REAL_PRECISION` to do it, only to realize that wasn't going to work.

Here's a solution that may work (or should I say, *may have worked*) for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  json_t *json = json_object();

  json_object_set_new(json, "foo", json_real(round(100000 * 123.123456789) / 100000));
  printf("Output of json_dumps() for 123.123456789: %s\n", json_dumps(json, 0));
  printf("Again, but using JSON_REAL_PRECISION(5) : %s\n", json_dumps(json, JSON_REAL_PRECISION(5)));

  return 0;
}
```